# Increase quality of OCR using windows.media.ocr in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, ocr

I have a UWP app and I need to OCR a document.

I use the API of Windows.Media.Ocr (OcrEngine.RecognizeAsync(SoftwareBitmap))

In some cases, the recognized text is not perfect, especially for underlined text, even for "normal" printed plain English text, coming from a scanned book.

Is there any way to configure the API or to run some operations (e.g. preprocessing of images) to get a better recognition quality?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid currently  there is no such property for  OcrEngine, if you do want this feature, please feel free post your requirement with windows feed backhub.

Comment: Do you have at least any best practice on the type of image to feed to the OCR? e.g. higher resolution, any preprocessing that could add value, etc.?

Comment: There is no limit for the image type,  but higher resolution image could be  better recognize. For image type we suggest use png or bmp.

Comment: Thanks @NicoZhu-MSFT, if you turn your comment into an answer I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to configure the API or to run some operations (e.g. preprocessing of images) to get a better recognition quality?

I'm afraid currently there is no such property for OcrEngine, if you do want this feature, please feel free post your requirement with windows feed backhub. There is no limit for the image type, but higher resolution image could be better recognize. For image type we suggest use png or bmp.